# Why don't hook_file_insert() and hook_file_presave() need the cache cleared to work?

Tags: 7, hooks

I think all hooks need the cache tto be cleared to work (or at least I thought until now), but it seems that these particular hooks don't need the cache to be cleared. I tried this even on a clean Drupal 7 installation.

Does anybody knows how this magic happens? I thought may be cache iscleared when files or nodes are saved, but I didn't see that.

Comment: Do you mean to clear the cache to make Drupal notice there is a new hook implementation? Did you try editing an enabled module, add that hook, and see if Drupal invokes it too? Are you sure that you don't do something that causes the cache to be cleared? There some pages that do that.

Comment: Yes. But it's not needed for file hooks it seems and that's interesting to me. I thought it might be contrib module so I tried the same thing on clean install. Same applies.